# Facebook Customer Chat Plug In Issue

Tags: plugins, chat, facebook-messenger

So I'm trying to integrate facebook chat plug-in into my website. So to start off, I went about my task by first following the guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/

It was quite simple and intuitive. However when I plugged in my code to my website, I actually wasn't able to render the chat widget. Now I've looked up possible solutions, a number of helpful people recommended that I make sure my domain is whitelisted. It was in fact! I also don't have any error appear on my console.

I do want to point out that I my chatbot isn't currently live since my team is currently developing it. I remember that being no problem a few months ago (Late July 2018). So long as one of my team members with admin privileges was already logged into facebook, they'd be able to see the chat widget.

Is that the problem - i.e. facebook updated their systems so that only live bots can be seen on websites regardless of whether a team member is looking at it or not.

I appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from our [docs](https://docs.amio.io/docs/facebook-messenger-entry-points-from-webpage) I found 1 more hint to whitelisting:

- **The plugin has to be served over HTTPS**.

Is it possible that it's your case? Sorry, I can't say if the not-live bot is of an issue.  :-/

Comment: Hi! Well first, I'd like to thank you for replying! So the website I've whitelisted does in fact using https. Also, when I test the widget on my local machine - i.e. built quick flask applications that serve html pages. I make sure to ngrok as a reverse proxy. I'm still exploring what could be wrong and when I do eventually figure out what's wrong, I'll make sure to post about it. Something I'm trying now is bringing my app live to see if that will change my situation - I've set my submission for "pages_messaging".

Comment: @ekram67 Try to connect a new FB Page via Amio (https://https;//app.amio.io/signup) then setup the chat plugin again (https://docs.amio.io/docs/facebook-messenger-entry-points-from-webpage). In case it works then it means that there's something wrong with your FB App. Let me know.

Comment: I ended up following your guide and it worked! Something I'd like to add is that when I tried it again, I had by that point set up a business manager account for my team. So that could have also contributed to the success?

Comment: @ekram67 I don't think so but everything is possible. :) The list we maintain should get you started without the Business Manager Account.

Comment: Actually, while testing, its possible that the bug could have been that the plug-in seems to work on chrome, but it didn't render over firefox.